# How to show all users in dockers group?

Tags: linux, docker, usergroups

How can I find out which users are in the docker group and allowed to start docker containers? (Docker 1.12.1)

Answer (score 33):

You can use the following:

```
grep /etc/group -e "docker"
grep /etc/group -e "sudo"
```

Answer (score 16):

Docker creates the `docker` group, but also any sudoers can use Docker, so you need to check two group memberships:

```
getent group sudo
getent group docker
```